# If textbox is empty or textbox is less than 3

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How do I fix this code? Theres an error if the textbox is empty.

```
 Private Sub MetroButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton1.Click

    If BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text < 3 Or BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("must have atleast 3 pesos profit")
    End If

End Sub
```

what I want is to display an error message if textbox.text is < 3 or if textbox.text is empty

Comment: Start by putting `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file, then read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Convert the **String** value in your TextBox to an **Integer** with [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use val() :-
If val(BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text) < 3 or val(BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text) = 0 Then MsgBox("must have atleast 3 pesos profit") End If
And manage the textbox allow only numbers. 
Actually use are comparing number to string. Use the above code it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn Option Strict On.  There are only a few edge cases where it allows something to succeed with something that wouldn't succeed without it, and those generally trivial to rewrite. What it does is the same actions that you would be doing, but it makes the possible type failures less clear.

```
If BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text < 3 Or BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text = "" Then
```

Because you have Option Strict Off, this gets treated as

```
If CInt(BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text) < 3 Or BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text = "" Then
```

CInt succeeds on Nothing, returning 0, but fails on "", throwing an exception.  Since you are using Or instead of OrElse both conditions will always be evaluated.  Also, you have the condition that will cause an exception first, so whenever your textbox is empty it throws an exception.

You could rewite that as: 
    If BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text = "" OrElse BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text < 3 Then

And everything would work correctly.  But I really wouldn't recommend it, because without knowing what is going on behind the scenes, it is fragile.

If you rewite it as:

```
Dim bunifuMaterial2 as Integer

If not Integer.TryParse(BunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text, bunifuMaterial2) OrElse bunifuMaterial2 < 3 Then
```

Not only will you avoid the exception on empty, you'll avoid the exception if they enter a non numeric value such as "cat" as well.